# How to retrieve an object from a Python Dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying to retrieve an object that I've placed into a dictionary, but every time I try to retrieve it I receive an error:

```
  class CSVEntry:
    lat = []
    lon = []
    count = 0

  # Create dictionary for tracking inputs
  dict = defaultdict(list)

  # Lookup the zipcode (returns an integer value)
  zipcode = ConvertLatLonToZip(row[latCol], row[lonCol])

  # If the zipcode is already in the dictionary, update it with the new count
  if zipcode in dict:
    oldEntry = dict[zipcode]
    oldEntry.lat.append(row[latCol])
    oldEntry.lon.append(row[lonCol])
    oldEntry.count = dict[zipcode].count + 1

  # Otherwise, make a new entry
  else:
    entry = CSVEntry()
    entry.lat.append(row[latCol])
    entry.lon.append(row[lonCol])
    entry.count = 1

    # Hash on the zipcode
    dict[zipcode].append(entry)
```

It has no problem inserting entries into the dictionary, but as soon as it finds a duplicate, it fails with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ParseCSV.py", line 125, in <module>
    oldEntry.lat.append(row[latCol])
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lat'
```

I apologize if this is a duplicate or a ridiculously simple question. I'm a beginner to Python and I searched for a long while before deciding to post.

EDIT: Added the definition of dict

Comment: What is `dict` here?  What does `ConvertLatLonToZip` return?

Comment: dict is set to "dict = defaultdict(list)" and ConvertLatLonToZip returns an integer zipcode value

Comment: You are doing something weird: `dict[zipcode].append(entry)` clearly suggests that `dict[zipcode]` is a **list**. No wonder `dict[zipcode].lat` throws an AttributeError.

Comment: Thanks freakish -- this helped me fix it. I needed to do dict[zipcode] = entry, instead of appending. Silly mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Right now `oldEntry` is a `list`.  It looks like you want to change

```
if zipcode in dict:
    oldEntry = dict[zipcode]
    oldEntry.lat.append(row[latCol])
    oldEntry.lon.append(row[lonCol])
    oldEntry.count = dict[zipcode].count + 1
```

to

```
if zipcode in dict:
    oldEntry = dict[zipcode][0]
    oldEntry.lat.append(row[latCol])
    oldEntry.lon.append(row[lonCol])
    oldEntry.count += 1
```

That being said, it might make more sense to simply create a new `CSVEntry` object and append it to `dict[zipcode]`  Alternatively, you could make `dict` a `defaultdict` containing `CSVEntry` objects, meaning that you wouldn't have to check whether zipcode was in dict.  This would give you code like:

```
zip_dict = collections.defaultdict(CSVEntry)
zip_dict[zipcode].lat.append(row[latCol])
zip_dict[zipcode].lon.append(row[longCol])
zip_dict[zipcode].count += 1
```

This is likely the easiest way to solve your problem.  On a sidenote, you want to avoid naming a variable `dict` as that overwrites the builtin `dict` type.

Answer (score 0):

You made yourself a defaultdict containing lists. When you call `dict[zipcode].append(entry)`,  Python creates a new list and you insert your entry in that list. However, when you do `oldEntry = dict[zipcode]`, you take that list and treat it as though it were a CSVEntry.

You should use a plain dict and insert your entries like so:

```
dict[zipcode] = entry
```

or append your item to the entry:

```
dict[zipcode].append(newEntry)
```

---

The point of a `defaultdict` is to abstract away the search for existing items. If you make a defaultdict of lists, you should not look for the entry in your dictionary, but simply append new ones when necessary; the defaultdict will take care of giving you a new list to play with when you ask for a non-existing key.